# ASP.NET Core - SAML2 ITFoxtec - Two IDP/Metadata

Tags: asp.net-core, itfoxtec-identity-saml2

Currently, I'm using `ITFoxTec` for our `ASP.NET Core` project for `SAML2` Authentication, and is working fine, but on the policy of our company, we have to use 2(two) Idp/Metadata, one if normal users, and one is for admin users, now our is procedure is like this.

1. All our employees can access the web application using the IdP/Metadata for normal users.
2. After the authentication, the system must detect if the user has the role of admin
3. If the user is admin he will log out from the normal user authentication, and redirect the user to the admin user SAML2 Authentication.

For `ITFoxtec`, I just followed the codes on this page:
https://www.itfoxtec.com/identitysaml2

I'm very new at this so I hope someone can help me with this, thanks everyone, I promise that if I have gain more on being a software developer, I will also share my solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement support for multiple IdPs, I have [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59761654/can-itfoxtec-saml2-supprot-multiple-idps) a question about multiple IdPs support. And two related answers [multiple tenant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66595064/how-i-setup-flow-of-multiple-tenant-in-azure-ad-asp-net-core-itfoxtec) and [multiple certificates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58959258/multiple-certificates-for-issuer-itfoxtec-identity-saml2).

Comment: Hi Anders thanks for this, will try this, sorry for very late response.