# Implement SAML2 for multiple IDPs w/ .Net Core 5 MVC

Tags: itfoxtec-identity-saml2

I am wanting to use your software ITfoxtec Identity Saml2 to implement SAML2 for multiple IDPs w/ .Net Core 5 MVC

I only see examples for a single configuration within the appsettings.json file and want to know if your software will support multiple configurations and/or how to authenticate from different IDPs.

Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: What software are you referring to?

Comment: Sorry…messed up my tags. itfoxtec saml

Answer (score 1):

You can implement support for multiple IdPs you self and thereby get around the appsettings.json file problem. I have [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59761654/can-itfoxtec-saml2-supprot-multiple-idps) a question about multiple IdPs support. And two related answers [multiple tenant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66595064/how-i-setup-flow-of-multiple-tenant-in-azure-ad-asp-net-core-itfoxtec) and [multiple certificates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58959258/multiple-certificates-for-issuer-itfoxtec-identity-saml2).