How can I use ITFoxtec.identity.saml2.0 in my ASP.NET Core 8.0 Web API project?
Can you show me the configure in program.cs?
I don't know how to write in the program.cs with add saml2 step
builder.Services.AddSaml2(options =>
{
    // I don't know how to add
options.SPOptions.EntityId = new EntityId("https
    options.SPOptions.ReturnUrl = new Uri("https://localhost:7003/signin-saml"); // 配置 SAML 回调 URL

    var idp = new IdentityProvider(new EntityId("https://your-idp-metadata-url"), options.SPOptions)
    {
        LoadMetadata = true,
        AllowUnsolicitedAuthnResponse = true,
        SingleSignOnServiceUrl = new Uri("https://your-idp-sso-url"), // 替换为实际的 IdP SSO URL
        SingleLogoutServiceUrl = new Uri("https://your-idp-slo-url") // 替换为实际的 IdP SLO URL
    };
    options.IdentityProviders.Add(idp);
});

Thank you for helping and showing me some demo code.
I am trying to integrate the ITFoxTec SAML package into it.
I have everything working except a method in my MetadataController class.

Hi lamchCCC, have you check the ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2 sample test code?

Please take a look at the documentation https://www.itfoxtec.com/IdentitySaml2
And the ASP.NET core 8.0 sample https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/tree/main/test/TestWebAppCore

If I have multiple Idp，how should I configure？

Please look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69832661/implement-saml2-for-multiple-idps-w-net-core-5-mvc
